# Is it okay to say "We are no more in the 20th century"? Using "no more" with periods of time

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, sentence-choice, formal-language, informal-language

The most correct form is *"We are no longer in the 20th century"*. But saying *"We are **no more** in the 20th century"* or *"We are in the 20th century **no more**"* is also correct? Is it possible to use "no more" with **periods of time** in formal, semi-formal and informal speech as well as writing?

Comment: To describe someone or something as _being no more_ is often taken to mean that that person or thing is dead.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**no more** can have the same the meaning as **no longer** and, up until 1840, it was more widely used. Here is a typical example:

> He instantly determined to be **no more** a slave. - *The works of Hannah More, Hannah More, 1804*

> We are **no more** in the 20th century.

This sentence is therefore grammatically correct, though dated. There is a further problem: **no more** is often used in modern formal writing and rhetoric in the set phrase **no more ... than**. In your sentence, we expect a than-clause, and it doesn't come. Here is an example:

> He is **no more** a simple soul than Tolstoy's Levin is a peasant. -*Modern poetry studies, 1974*

> We are in the 20th century **no more**.

This avoids the expectation of a than-clause, but sounds to me like [anastrophe](https://www.britannica.com/art/inversion-literature) (literary inversion).

For modern formal writing, **no longer** is perfectly clear, and would be my preferred option.

> We are **no longer** in the 20th century.

For informal speech, you would be more likely to use **any more** (UK) or **anymore** (US):

> We aren't in the 20th century **any more**.
> Love don't live here **anymore** - *Song lyrics, Rose Royce, 1974*

Comment: Thank you. I get it like this: "Yes, you can use "no more" in the middle and in the end while talking about "time periods" in formal speech. However using it in the middle would be a little bit weird, because people would expect a "than". P.S. I need to edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Btw, is "any more" not a formal phrase ?

Comment: @Xfce4 you can use **no more** in the middle, but it's potentially confusing. You can use it in the end, but it sounds literary. In my opinion, **no longer** in mid position is the best option for formal english. I would not regard **any more**  meaning **no longer** as formal. The only example in the Cambridge dictionary is spoken. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/any-more

Comment: JavaLatte, Duolingo.com marked me wrong for using "no more" instead of "no longer" in the translation of "Nous ne sommes plus au vingtième siècle". That is why I asked.

Comment: @Xfce4 no more and no longer do not have the same meaning no longer and the us anymore have the same meaning.

Comment: @XFce4 **no more** is a literal translation of **ne... plus**. It almost works but, for the reasons that I have outlined, **no longer** is the more natural translation.

Comment: If I was a slave I would want it to stop and that is the correct interpretation. **He instantly determined to stop being a slave.** Not *He instantly determined to be no longer a slave.*   He instantly determined to be no more a slave. - The works of Hannah More, Hannah More, 1804 Now insert Stop instead of longer in We are no more in the 20th century.

Comment: Yes I accept what you are saying, but my point is *no more* is not related to time now or previously. In some instances it may have appeared that way but when you try different substitutions it does not compute

Comment: @Brad I don't see any significant semantic difference between "He instantly determined to stop being a slave" and  "He instantly determined to no longer be a slave", so I don't see how you can claim that it means the one but doesn't mean the other.

Comment: From my stance and I am an engineer not an academic, there is a world of difference between stopping or ending something and what happens as a function of time. The end result maybe the same but the process is not.  See my clarification at the bottom of my answer

Comment: @Brad: "We have stopped being in the 20th century"? That doesn't sound grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @Stef Yes depending on use; but can we connect grammar, meaning, tense  altogether in the same question?  "We are no longer in the 20th century" = "We are not in the 20th century (time period)" "We have stopped being in the 20th century" = "we have been in the 20th century but we no longer are.  **"We are no more in the 20th century" = "we died in the  20th century"**

Comment: Wow, this escalated quickly! I didn't die in the 20th century. You're right, this sentence can have two interpretations.

Comment: "This parrot is no more!" Monty Python's Flying Circus, 1969. https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/10134852-this-parrot-is-no-more-it-has-ceased-to-be#:~:text=Sign%20Up%20Now-,This%20parrot%20is%20no%20more!,gone%20to%20meet%20its%20maker!

Comment: Now if you read my answer. What I say is "we should use an alternative......" and I suggest what and why we should use it. Then  everybody is arguing about my alternative without reading and then properly considering what has been written in a) the question and b) the other answers.

Comment: Toto, we are not in Kansas anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of your *"We are no more in the 20th century"* I would suggest we should use the sentence

> "We are not in the 20th century any more" *(the 20th century has ended)*

as an alternative to

> "We are no longer in the 20th century" (*we are not in this time period*)

Why we may be tempted to use " more" in the way you describe is because of the similarities with *"any more" (us anymore) meaning any longer and the use of More to form the comparative of many adjectives* and adverbs:
In the second case we would need something to compare. The comparison maybe obvious or implied

> He finds physics far/much more difficult than other science subjects.

> She couldn't be more beautiful

Therefore the following sentence would be correct.

"We are no more in the 20th century than.."

---

However we are actually substituting more for longer. This we cannot do, more means greater or larger not longer. It can mean increasingly but again this makes no sense in this context.

What we really need to do is rearrange the sentence.

***"We are not in the 20th century any more"***

---

To clarify my point

Longer is related to time

> we no longer have eggs

at this time and maybe forever (who knows) we have no eggs.

More is related to quantity, (increasingly, larger or extra number or amount).

> we have no more eggs

We do not have any eggs, the eggs have stopped, egg production has ended.

*In essence the result is the same **No eggs** but the meaning is very different*

---

**anymore** [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anymore) adverb [ not gradable ] US (used esp. in negative statements) any longer:  (UK usually **any more**)

**more**; [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/more) determiner, pronoun, adverb

a larger or extra number or amount:

increasingly:

used to form the comparative of many adjectives and adverbs:

Comment: Thank you. But your answer contradicts with JavaLatte's answer. Is it due to the region? Btw, are you a native speaker?

Comment: I am English; why I posted a separate answer. He states at the end "For formal writing, no longer is perfectly clear. For informal speech, you would be more likely to use anymore": Which I totally agree with. I don't agree with *We are no more in the 20th century. This sentence is grammatically correct*. I think it is incorrect.

Comment: It is the use of any more that has clouded things.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any-more-or-anymore..... *We are not **any** more in the 20th century*. but a better construction is *We are not in the 20th century any more*

Comment: When two native speakers have different opinions it is difficult for non native speakers to decide :) According to this [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/no-more-not-any-more?q=no+more) JavaLatte seems to be correct about "no more" being in the end. If it is correct in the end,  it should be -according to the pattern- possible in the middle too. Isn't it so?

Comment: I do not see the connection In the case I presume you refer to *The army has arrived. We should fear no more*. I would presume you interpret it as *The army has arrived. We should fear no longer* However, On the page you refer to it is defined as **We use no more and not any more as adverbs to talk about something stopping or ending**. Therefore I would interpret as *The army has arrived. We should fear no more (stop-have no fear).* One of the meanings of more is *increasingly* the opposite is thus reduce; the ultimate reduction is to stop. "We are **stopping** in the 20th century" ??

Comment: "We use no more and not any more as adverbs to talk about something stopping or ending". We should keep in mind that this explanation might not be complete. The actual explanation might be more broad, including more words (and phrases) than "stopping" and "ending", but the dictionary might have preferred to provide a quick and practical explanation.

Comment: Sounds very formal but perfectly normal for formal speeches/writing

Answer (score -2):

***It is not possible to use  "no more" with periods of time*** in formal, semi-formal and informal speech as well as writing? In this relation we would use, if needed, the alternative

> any more or anymore (us)

> anymore adverb;(also any more):[C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anymore?q=ANY%20MORE)(used esp. in negative statements) any longer:

The original form in the question was

> "We are no longer in the 20th century".

> no longer (also not any longer) [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-longer) ; in the past but not now:

***yes we can use any more instead of no longer***

---

It is not advisable to use the form

> "We are no more in the 20th century".

Why! try it in shortened form.

> "**We are no more**"

This means we have ceased, stopped, it is not related to time it is an action "Stop". In fact it is already established on this site that no more means cessation. (***He is no more, means he is deceased***).

This usage of no more to mean cease, stop or end, has be documented since Shakespearian times ([sigh no-more](https://www.cieliterature.com/sigh-no-more-ladies/)) and remains so today.

---

Shakespeare obviously did not mean *"Sigh in the past but not now ladies*",

What he meant was *"Cease/stop your sighing ladies"*,

However his version is so much better but alas we art nay longeth'r in the 16th century.

Sigheth nay m're ladies, sigheth nay m're, men w're deceiv'rs ev'r, one foot in flote and one on sh're,